# Setting an image as the default background for the entire application

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm creating a solution where it's completely done in white details about an image in the background. I would like to set the image directly in the app.component so you do not have to call it again. I'm doing it this way:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { initFirebase } from './shared/firebase.common';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'ns-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**app.component.scss**

```
.fullscreen {
  background-image: url('~/images/bg-circles.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ScrollView class="fullscreen">
  <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
</ScrollView>
```

**and my solution structure**

```
src
 |- app
     |- app.component.ts
     |- app.component.html
     |- app.component.scss
     |- app.module.ts
     |- // and more files...
 |- images
     |- bg-circles.png
```

I already tried to put the images folder inside the folder `app`, already tried to reference directly using a path with points (for example `../images/bg-circles.png`) but still I did not succeed.

Could someone help me with this? give me an example (that works), or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put the image into the assets folder or add your images folder to your assets array in your `angular.json` file. Then you will reference the image with an absolute path in your css.

If you move your images folder to your assets folder (my recommendation) it will look something like this:

```
.fullscreen {
  background-image: url('/assets/images/bg-circles.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```